# Login authentication with HTTP POST

Tags: flutter, api, dart, rest

I'm trying to implement simple login authentication with **HTTP POST** but my `response.statusCode == 200` always, and it allows me to go to the Next page.

**Here is my simple authentication function:**

```
Future<void> login() async {
if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://myAPI/login"),
      body: ({
        'LoginId': emailController.text,
        'Password': passwordontroller.text
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Second()));
  } else {
    print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Blank field is not allowed")));
}
```

}

I have doubts in my Json parameters body.

**Here is my Json Response:**
[image]

**And here my TextFormField with emailController and passwordController:**

```
 TextFormField(
            controller:
                emailController, //==========================================
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller:
                passwordontroller, //=========================================
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.password)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 45,
          ),
          OutlinedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                login();
              },
```

Comment: It has to do with your server side logic, when are you returning status code 200? It should be when the credentials match.

Comment: The HTTP 200 OK success status response code that means your request is success, when you check your API on postman it also gives the status code 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statusCode 200 just means you got a succesfull response from the server. This will most likely not say anything about the actual authentication status of the data you send, you can "most likely" find the in the response body.